# Docker View Historical Logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Background**:

For Development purposes I do a lot of `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose stop`.

To view logs of a container I do either

```
- docker logs --details --since=1m -t -f container_name
or
- docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' container_name
  cat path-from-previous
```

The problem is when I want to view 10 days older logs, there are none, the logs just have todays logs.

when I do a `docker inspect container_name` I get the following

```
"Created": "todays-timestamp"
```

my logging is the default config.

```
"LogConfig": {
     "Type": "json-file",
     "Config": {}
 },
```

Comment: If Docker Compose deletes an old container (say, because the image you're running changes) it will delete the container's logs with it.  If you need historical logs across container recreation you'll need to set up some sort of system to capture them.

Comment: ok will take a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the reason behind this is because there is no rotation in your docker-logs.

in case you are using a linux system go to:

```
/etc/logrotate.d/
```

and create the file **docker-container** like this => /etc/logrotate.d/docker-container

write this into the file:

```
 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  compress
  missingok
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
}
```

it takes all builded images and their daily log and rotates + compress them.

you can test this with:

```
logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.d/docker-container
```

enter your docker folder **/var/lib/docker/containers/[CONTAINER ID]/**  and you can see the rotation.

reference: https://sandro-keil.de/blog/logrotate-for-docker-container/

Comment: thanks, i ended up using docker's own log rotate based on file size (it wad mentioned in the link u shared)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it only fit to write how it is done in docker as that is missing from this post.

As far as I've found there are 2 methods (3 if you count in the `docker run` terminal command). One works "automatically" for new/recreated logs and the other is a part of docker-compose. Below you will find 2 methods for setting up logging for you docker containers.

## Automatic procedure

On the host machine running docker you have (or should have) a file named `deamon.json`. It is (on Linux) located in `/etc/docker/`. If the file doesn't exist you can create it. You can add the following to the file:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3"
  }
}
```

This should make so that you create logs at a max size of 10 mb and there should consist a max of 3 logs at any time, but it will only work on new or recreated containers.

## docker-compose.yml procedure

As mentioned you can also set up your docker-compose to take care of the logging rotation. It is done by adding the following `logging` section to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
services:
    <service-name>: ...
        ...
        logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-size: "10m"
                max-file: "3"
```

This should make so that you create logs at a max size of 10 mb and there should consist a max of 3 logs at any time, and it will work if you use the docker compose file for creating your container.